# How can I run this command line in the background?

Tags: bash, shell

I have this

```
script -q -c "continuously_running_command" /dev/null > out
```

When I have the above command line running I can stop it by doing `CTRL+C`

However I'd like to run the above commandline in back ground  so that I can stop it by doing `kill -9 %1`

But when I try to run this

```
script -q -c "continuously_running_command" /dev/null > out &
```

I get

```
[2]+  Stopped (tty output)       script -q -c "continuously_running_command" /dev/null 1>out
```

Question:

How can I run the above commandline in back ground?

Answer (score 1):

In order to background a process with redirection to a file, you must also redirect stderr. With stdout and stderr redirected, you can then background the process:

```
script -q -c "continuously_running_command" /dev/null > out 2>&1 &
```

Fully working example:

```
#!/bin/bash

i=$((0+0))

while test "$i" -lt 100; do

    ((i+=1))
    echo "$i"
    sleep 1

done
```

Running the script and tail of output file while backgrounded:

```
alchemy:~/scr/tmp/stack> ./back.sh > outfile 2>&1 &
[1] 31779
alchemy:~/scr/tmp/stack> tailf outfile
10
11
12
13
14
...
100
[1]+  Done                    ./back.sh > outfile 2>&1
```

In the case of:

```
 script -q -c "continuously_running_command" /dev/null
```

The problem in in this case is the fact that `script` itself causes redirection of all dialog with script to FILE, in this case to `/dev/null`. So you need to simply issue the command without redirecting to /dev/null or just redirect stderr to out:

```
script -q -c "continuously_running_command" out 2>&1 &
```

or

```
script -q -c "continuously_running_command" /dev/null/ 2>out &
```

Comment: This does not work. This is pretty much same as what I have and the commandline just stops.

Comment: Hmm. redirecting stdout to file and then redirecting stderr to stdout should then allow backgrounding file. You are getting the exact same output?

Comment: @abc What is your script? Do you expect output after passing /dev/null and a command line argument. The problem is NOT with the redirection method I posted. Full example added to answer.

Comment: Who knows - anonymous downvoting allows anyone to downvote any answer without providing any reason. A "Doesn't work for me" or "I don't like the color of your socks" are legitimate reasons.